# Why does Spacer() inside SingleChildScrollView widget or ListView widget throws an error?

Tags: flutter

I am currently new to flutter.I have a question.I have a simple login interface as:

```
Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.face,
                size: 128,
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45),
              child: TextFormField(
                validator: (value) =>
                    value == null || value.isEmpty ? 'Enter username' : null,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                inputFormatters: [
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                ],
                controller: usernameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hoverColor: Colors.red,
                    border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: BorderSide(),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
                    hintText: 'Username',
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                      color: Theme.of(context).hintColor,
                    )),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45, vertical: 25),
              child: TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter some text';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                controller: passwordController,
                obscureText: isSecured,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: const OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(50))),
                  focusedBorder: const OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(60))),
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isSecured = !isSecured;
                          showpassWord = isSecured
                              ? Icons.remove_red_eye
                              : Icons.visibility_off;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(showpassWord)),
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).hintColor),
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 85),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                        Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary)),
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return LoginPage(
                            username: usernameController.text.toString(),
                            password: passwordController.text.toString(),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Text('Dont have account?'),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text(
                    'SignUp',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

It works perfectly fine when using SizedBox to give some space between each TextField .Now the problem lies when I replace my SizedBox with a Spacer() widget.

After using Spacer instead of Sizedbox my code looks like:

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
        title: Text('MyApp', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.titleLarge),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.message,
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.settings,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.face,
                size: 128,
                color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color,
              ),
            ),
          const  Spacer(
              flex:1
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45),
              child: TextFormField(
                validator: (value) =>
                    value == null || value.isEmpty ? 'Enter username' : null,
                controller: usernameController,
              ),
            ),
          const Spacer(
              flex:1
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45, vertical: 25),
              child: TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter some text';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                controller: passwordController,
                obscureText: isSecured,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          isSecured = !isSecured;
                          showpassWord = isSecured
                              ? Icons.remove_red_eye
                              : Icons.visibility_off;
                        });
                      },
                      icon: Icon(showpassWord)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 85),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) {
                          return LoginPage(
                            username: usernameController.text.toString(),
                            password: passwordController.text.toString(),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                const Text('Dont have account?'),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text(
                    'SignUp',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
              const Spacer(
              flex: 2,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

It gives me error as:

```
The following assertion was thrown while applying parent data.:
Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.


The ParentDataWidget Expanded(flex: 1) wants to apply ParentData of type FlexParentData to a RenderObject, which has been set up to accept ParentData of incompatible type ParentData.

Usually, this means that the Expanded widget has the wrong ancestor RenderObjectWidget. Typically, Expanded widgets are placed directly inside Flex widgets.
The offending Expanded is currently placed inside a RepaintBoundary widget.
```

Why can't I use spacer() inside SingleChildScrollView() or ListView()?

Comment: It would solve the problem but didnt answer my question.As I am curious why can't I use it rather than what are other solutions @basti394

Comment: Okay, I see. I even deleted my comment, because I read that its better habit to use SizedBod/Spacer.

Comment: Can you include `Spacer` on your snippet and share a sample widget from scaffold's body, (decoration classes can be removed)

Comment: ScrollView() is not a Flex container like Row or Column and Spacer can only be used in such Widgets (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html). Thats because Spacer hasn't a intrinsic height and a ListView tries to take up as much vertical space as it can.

Comment: Also can you describe/add an image what are you trying to archive?

Answer (score 2):

**Spacer** can not **directly** be used with **SingleChildScrollView**. In Layman's terms, **Spacer** works by calculating the available space, distributing it amongst the children of a Row or Column and then filling up the remaining space. With **SingleChildScrollView**, the constraints are **unbounded(infinite)** because the content is supposed to be scrollable and **Spacer** can not perform its calculation, hence, the error it throws.

You can however use **Spacer** with **SingleChildScrollView** but you need to:

1. Use **LayoutBuilder** to get the available space.
2. Provide the space to the content of the SingleChildScrollView (most likely by using **ConstrainedBox**)
3. Use **IntrinsicHeight** to make the Column as big as its contents.

You can find this in Flutter's official documentation site [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SingleChildScrollView-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

A ListView or SingleChildScrollView widget will provide infinite height (Constraints){default on vertical} and `Spacer()` (which is an Expanded) widget also try to take as much space it can get. You can think of scrollable widget is offering infinite space and `Spacer` is trying to access as much spacer it can get which is infinite. This is where error occurs.

I will suggest checking [layout/constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints)

refactored scaffold by replacing flex value with layoutBuilder constraints height.

```dart
body: LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (context, constraints) {
    final height = constraints.maxHeight;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Form(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Center(child: Icon(Icons.face, size: 128, color: Theme.of(context).iconTheme.color)),
            SizedBox(height: height * .1), //based on question flex
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45),
              child: TextFormField(
                validator: (value) => value == null || value.isEmpty ? 'Enter username' : null,
                // controller: usernameController,
              ),
            ),
            // SizedBox(height: height * .1), //based on question flex//! better without it
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 45, vertical: 25),
              child: TextFormField(
                validator: (value) {
                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                    return 'Please enter some text';
                  }
                  return null;
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: 'Password',
                  suffixIcon: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(showpassWord)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 85),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text(
                  'Login',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                const Text('Dont have account?'),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text(
                    'SignUp',
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: height * .2,
            ), //based on question flex
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```